# Sum over an axis using matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, gpgpu

Given a 4D matrix A of shape NxCxHxW, I want to calculate 4D matrix B of shape Nx1xHxW where b is the sum of a over the 2nd dimension.

```
for n in range(N):
  for h in range(H):
    for w in range(W):
      b[n][0][h][w] = 0
      for c in range(C):
        b[n][0][h][w] += a[n][c][h][w]
```

Since the code is on GPU, I can only use the 4D matrix multiplication function gemm, i.e. B = A * C. What should be the matrix C?